# how to get such an array [{ id: '198', included: true }] from such an array [{ '198': true }]

Tags: javascript, reactjs

how to get newArray from this array
forEach,map

```
  const array = [
      { id: '198', included: true },
      { id: '199', included: true },
      { id: '202', included: false },
    ];
    
    const newObj = { '198': true , '199': true , '202': false };
```

Comment: `const newArray = array.map(({id, included}) => ({ [id]: included }));`

Comment: sorry please i changed my code ,

Comment: `const newObj = array.reduce((res, { id, included }) => ({ ...res, [id]: included }), {})`

Answer (score 0):

If you want get newObj from array like your body question. Try this with reduce is shorten

```js
const array = [
          { id: '198', included: true },
          { id: '199', included: true },
          { id: '202', included: false },
        ];
    const newObj = array.reduce((prev, curr) => ({...prev, [curr.id]: curr.included}),{})
    console.log(newObj)
```

Comment: sorry please i changed my code ,

Comment: @Jhon I just have updated my post!

Comment: @Jhon use reduce i post in my answer is return object,  .map() will return array not object, .forEach() will make code line is longer

Answer (score 0):

User reduce function to create an Object from an array.

```js
const array = [
  { id: "198", included: true },
  { id: "199", included: true },
  { id: "202", included: false },
];

const result = array.reduce((acc, curr) => {
  acc[curr.id] = curr.included;
  return acc;
}, {});

console.log(result);
```